# How do I clean up my android emulator of unwanted applications?

Tags: android-emulator

I still have unwanted apps in my menu in the android emulator. The projects which have been deleted from the workspace are there on the emulator. How do I clean the emulator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is just to launch the emulator, go to `settings -> applications`. Then pick the unwanted applications and uninstall them.

Alternatively you can do `adb -e shell` while the emulator is running, find the .apk files in the file system (I think they're under /system/apps) and remove them manually.

One final solution is in Eclipse's Android Plugin (ADT), go to the file manager, find the .apk files and remove them.

Comment: Adi asks: How do you go to the file manager in ADT, please? I have found the apk in the File Explorer in the DDMS view, but I don't know how to delete it.

Comment: To delete it, after you select the file, you will notice there's a red minus icon on the top right corner of the panel. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to delete/uninstall unwanted apps from the android emulator just follow these steps:

1. Click and hold the app you want to delete/uninstall from the emulator.
2. You will be presented home screen with "**Uninstall** option on the top.
3. Drag and drop your app on **Uninstall** that's it the app is uninstalled from the emulator.

[image: Refer to the image attached.]

Comment: I do not see this behavior on API 19. Long press simply gives option to 'Remove from List'. On API 19, one has to choose App Info to find the Uninstall option.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer delete emulator and create newest.
It takes only one minute.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to `Wipe Data`:

[image]

In may case `Wipe Data` cleaned around 7GB while I had only one installed app!

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple and quick, just follow these two steps,

Go to AVD Manager,
[image]

Then simply, wipe the data of emulator.
[image]

It will be like brand new device.